# Adding a row to an m2m table using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the below representation in my models.py

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(SampignanUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ManyToManyField(Agent)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to create a rest endpoint where in i can have an agent apply for a particular project (i.e - create a row in the Project-agents table). Is there a particular way i can do this? Right now , i've tried the below approach

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/<int:project_id>/apply/', views.project_application, name='apply')
]
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def project_application(request, project_id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ProjectApplicationSerializer()
        // show an empty form to the user
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProjectApplicationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializers.py

```
class ProjectApplicationSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    agent = AgentSerializer
    project = ProjectSerializer
```

It doesnt seem to work however , i get the below error from Django

```
`child` is a required argument.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advice you to use `serializers.ModelSierializer`. So it will look like:

```
class ProjectModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = [..., 'agent',....] # you can use exclude also

   def to_representation(self, instance):
      self.fields['agent'] = AgentSerializer(many=True)
      return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Here, `ModelSerializer` automatically handle many to many field. Moreover, in showing your results you can return agent as an object in defining it in `to_representation(self, instance)` method of serializer. So it will not only return id of agents in array, but extra information as defined `AgentSerializer`. If you want to create many projects you should use `many=True` keyword in `ProjectModelSerializer`( `ProjectModelSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)`), and request body will change like this:

```
[
  {
   .... # project data,
   agents = [1,2,3,4,5,...], # primary keys of Agents
  },
  {
   .... # project data,
   agents = [1,2,3,4,5,...], # primary keys of Agents
  },
]
```